# shell and Pushgateway error: text format parsing error in line 1: expected float as value, got ",0.0"

Tags: shell

Follows is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`ps aux|awk 'NR>1{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\",pid=\""$2"\"},"$3"\nmemory_usage{process=\""$11"\",pid=\""$2"\"},"$4""}'`
curl -X POST -H  "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "$var" http://192.168.11.249:9091/metrics/job/testjob/instance/machine
```

but get error:

```
text format parsing error in line 1: expected float as value, got ",0.0"
```

Follows is input info:

```
memory_usage{process="-bash",pid="29653"},0.0
cpu_usage{process="[kworker/u8:2]",pid="30368"},0.0
memory_usage{process="[kworker/u8:2]",pid="30368"},0.0
cpu_usage{process="wget",pid="30409"},0.0
```

How to fix script error?

Thanks!

Comment: `How to fix script error?` remove the comma, Liek this one `\"},"$3`